# How to create and scan a .txt file and to and from a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginning Java programmer that is new around this site. I am working on **a Java project that involves the saving and reloading of .txt files**. I realize that there are many similar questions out there, but none of them are exactly what I am looking for. If I have mistaken, I am very sorry.

I am trying to design a Java program for a classroom when the teacher wants to assign new seats. First, I am going to explain my vision for the program. The program will allow you to *type in the students' names*, which it will separate into two separate ArrayLists, one for the boys in the class and another for the girls. I want *these ArrayLists to be saved somehow into a .txt file so they can be read later*. I have done this before with simple strings:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("list.txt");
        out.println("Bobby Joe");
        out.println("John Doe");
        out.close();
```

Is there a different way to do this with ArrayLists? The PrintWriter worked perfectly when I used simple strings. Another part of the program will *read those .txt files and import them into ArrayLists again*. There, it can use the ArrayLists to assign seats for the children in the class. I am completely unaware how to load .txt files.

I am pretty sure these are the only two parts of the program I will need help with, I can use the randomizer and other simple methods to program the rest.

I would really appreciate if you could help me create my Java program. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can loop on the list, and call out.println() with each element to write it in the file. To read files, read the Java IO tutorial. That's why it has been written. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the names to be written line-by-line.

Edit your writing method to write the names from a list:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("list.txt");
list.forEach(out::println);
out.close();
```

And then you can read them with something like this:

```
List<String> list = Files.lines(Paths.get("list.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use for this serialization:

[Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-an-object-to-file-in-java/)

Just write/read full ArrayList object to/from file.